# Is it right to synchronize a method when building an API

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, microservices

When building an `API` RESTful webservice which performs CRUD operations, is it a right practice to `synchronize` the methods? Or should we avoid synchronizing the methods since it reduces the performance. 
Could anyone please explain.

Answer (score 1):

It is not "right practice" or "best practice".

It doesn't even make sense to me.  In general.

A RESTful API consists of a URLs for making http / https "calls".  The notion of "synchronized" is foreign to this.

Now a there might be use-cases where it would make sense to use some form of mutual exclusion in the implementation of a RESTful API.  However, it is not clear that declaring Java API methods as `synchronized` gives the correct semantics.   Certainly not without knowing how your RESTful API is being mapped onto your Java methods and your domain objects.

If we are talking about mapped Java methods in a Spring `@RestController` class, declaring those methods as `synchronized` would result in mutual exclusion on the current instance of the controller class.  Spring controller objects are singletons, so you would end up processing your RESTful requests serially.  I can't see why you would want to do that.

The correct way to approach this is to work out what you are actually trying to achieve, and then look for ways to achieve it.  Don't go looking for a solution before you understand the problem.  And don't look for "best practice" justifications.  Think things through ... in the context of your problem.

**[There are no best practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164).**